# Liking Facebook pages on Android isn't working

Tags: android, facebook

I used the code below to like a Facebook page. Initially, it was working but not anymore. It shows the Like button but when it's clicked the login page shows up and liking is not working. Here is the code:

```
 likeWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView1 );
 likeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 String url = "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?" +
       "href=" + URLEncoder.encode("likeurl" ) + "&" +
       "layout=standard&" +
       "show_faces=false&" +
       "width=500&" +
       "action=like&" +
       "colorscheme=light&" +
       "access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode( "read_stream" );
 likeWebView.loadUrl( url );
```

Please give a solution.

Comment: Hey,
The same problem is with me,were u able to solve it?